# Kernel compilation not finding .config file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, linux-kernel

EDIT: Solved it, check my comment below.

I'm trying to compile a kernel with make O=$BUILD

Where build is the build path: BUILD=~/lab/build

But then I get this error:

```
*** Configuration file ".config" not found!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
make[3]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by`include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
```

Before I compiled I used the old config file for the new kernel by copying it to my kernel folder:

```
cp -vi /boot/config-3.13.0-45-generic .config
```

and then i ran:

```
make oldconfig
```

and entered all defaults.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: You better do `make menuconfig` first then copy the `.config` file and then do `make menuconfig` again. And then run your `make O=$BUILD`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got it to compile differently, check my comment below.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to compile now by doing 
make O=$BUILD oldconfig and also by doing a make mrproper in my kernel directory, and then running make O=$BUILD again.